# Multiply ViewControllers with GuestureRecognizers

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers (recorder and player) with tapGuestureRecognizers inside. I'm trying to use both of them in one place, lets call it container view controller, and replacing one with another with methods:

```
    private func displayContentController(content: UIViewController) {

    addChildViewController(content)
    content.view.frame = view.frame
    view.addSubview(content.view)
    content.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

private func hideContentController(content: UIViewController) {

    content.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    content.view.removeFromSuperview()
    content.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

This is container view controller code:

```
private let recorder = CMRecorder()
private let player   = CMPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    displayContentController(recorder)

    recorder.finishRecordingCallback = { url in

        self.hideContentController(self.recorder)
        self.displayContentController(self.player)
    }
}
```

Everything is ok with taping on recorder, but player don't want to recognize my taps. If I swap recorder with player (so player is loaded first), player has no problem with guesture recognizer. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem.

In my player view controller I have added imageView and forgot to set:

```
thumbnailView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```